# Error while logging in to a NIS server using the desktop GUI

Tags: users, opensuse, nis

When trying to login to a user account on an openSUSE based NIS server on a local network I receive the error message `Cannot enter home directory. Using /.`

The following is the console error message afterwards : `kstartupconfig4 does not exist or fails. The error code is 3. Check your installation.`

Both the server and client machines are running openSUSE 11.2 and are Virtual Machines. I am very new to linux thus googling for the error did not produce many results.

Comment: NIS? In 2016? My word.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your home directory is not mounted, or not mountable. Running `getent passwd MYUSER` on the master should show you the home directory for your user; is there a similar directory available on the client? If not, you will either need to share the home directory from the master over NFS, or make a parallel directory tree available.